# Parallel computing on GPU with using monitor

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I heard that if you use parallel computing on GPU with monitor, after 5-6 sec process will be closed. And it's fix in registry. I use openCL with AMD Radeon Vega 64. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if a single kernel instance runs over 5 seconds will the OS terminate it. Just design your kernels so they run in less than a second and you'll be fine (just queue up many of them to get the same amount of work done compared to a long-running kernel). Even at one second your desktop will be sluggish. To avoid that, keep kernel runtimes below 50 ms or less. Just run more of them. In other words, you can run GPGPU tasks for days and days, by running millions of short kernels.